# Proof that $\phi (n) \neq 50$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Like the question states, I'm curious how to go about doing this.

I found so far that if such an n does exist, then $n \in \Big[51,219 \Big]$, but I'm not sure if I took the right route with this one.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: What is $\phi(n)$?

Comment: Totient function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi(n) = 50$, then $50$ is the product of numbers of the form $(p - 1)p^\alpha$, where $p$ is prime and $\alpha \geq 0$. But $50 = 2 \times 5 \times 5$: although $2$ is $1$ less than a prime ($3$), neither $5$ nor $25$ is. We could try $10$, which is $1$ less than $11$, but that leaves us with a "loose" $5$.

To be better convinced, try solving $\phi(n) = 60$. One answer should immediately suggest itself: $n = 61$. Another answer is $n = 93$, this comes from the observation that $60 = 2 \times 30$. There may be more, you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is multiplicative with $\phi(p^d) = (p-1) p^{d-1}$ for primes $p$.
Each odd prime power, and each power of $2$ greater than $2$ itself gets at least one factor of $2$ from this, and $50$ is
divisible by $2$ but not $4$, so there can be only one of those, i.e. 
$n$ is either $2$ (which is easy to rule out) or a prime power.  The only other prime divisor of $50$ is $5$.  But $n$ can't be a power of $5$, since again that would contribute a factor of $4$.  Thus we must have $50 = p-1$ with $d=1$.
But $51$ is not prime...

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. How would a power of 5 contribute a factor of 4?

Comment: @Lerbi If $n$ is a power of $5$ then $\phi(5^d) = (5-1)\cdot 5^{d-1} = 4 \cdot 5^{d-1}$.

Comment: Ah. Duh. Thanks. Going from zero number theory to this by my second year in college is ... a lot to take in.

Comment: Truth be told, I had to look at it for a couple of minutes myself.  I had wondered the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the following easy fact: if $n$ has $k$ different prime factors, then $2^k$ divides $\phi(n)$ (hint: what's the formula for $\phi(n)$ in terms of prime factors of $n$?). It follows that $n$ can only have 1 distinct prime factor. Which means that $n=p^k$ for a prime $p$. But $\phi(p^k)=p^k(1-1/p)$.

So

$$p^{k-1}(p-1)=50,$$

and this has no solution for any $p,k$ since $50=2\cdot 5^2$.

Comment: Why does it follow that n can only have 1 distinct prime factor? Since 50 is 2*5*5?

Comment: 6 has two different prime factors, but $4=2^2$ does not divide $\phi(6)=2$.

Comment: @Lerbi: look at the "easy fact:" If it had more than 1 prime factor than 4 would have to divide $50$.

Comment: Man.  Number theory is the first course I've ever taken that truly makes me feel dumb.  Thanks

Comment: @Lerbi: 99% of number theory comes down to breaking stuff down into prime factors. With enough practice it'll make sense.